# Shorten repetitive CSS

Tags: css

I'm wondering if there is a way to shorten repetitive css code which only different by the given url.

the class is always named `.bg-login-[n]` and the url represents the same number.

The solution I'm consindering is to somehow combine CSS and JS to loop through an array of filenames. is there a simpler or "cleaner" way?

for example:

```
.bg-login-1{
  background: url(/images/login/login-1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

.bg-login-2{
  background: url(/images/login/login-2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

.bg-login-3{
  background: url(/images/login/login-3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

.bg-login-4{
  background: url(/images/login/login-4.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

.bg-login-5{
  background: url(/images/login/login-5.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: You can do this with a loop in JavaScript. - simply a loop which goes from 1 to 5 and setting different background property for each iteration.

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for

Answer (score 0):

No JS needed. Just repeat numbers or use SCSS for loop.

```css
.bg {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat:
}

.bg-1 {
  background-image: url(/images/login/login-1.jpg);
}

.bg-2 {
  background-image: url(/images/login/login-2.jpg);
}

/* ... */

/* SCSS */
@for $i from 1 through N {
  .bg-#{$i} {
    background-image: url(/images/login/login-#{$i}.jpg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bg-login-1 {
  background-image: url(/images/login/login-1.jpg);
}

.bg-login-2 {
  background-image: url(/images/login/login-2.jpg);
}

.bg-login-3 {
  background-image: url(/images/login/login-3.jpg);
}

.bg-login-4 {
  background-image: url(/images/login/login-4.jpg);
}

.bg-login-5 {
  background-image: url(/images/login/login-5.jpg);
}
```

And for the last three properties, do this:

```
.bg-login-1,
.bg-login-2,
.bg-login-3,
.bg-login-4,
.bg-login-5 {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
}
```

or do this:

```
.bg-login {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add classname `bg-login` to all the button.

```
<script>
const btns = document.getElementsByClassName('bg-login'); //get all the buttons
const i=1;
for(const btn in btns){
    btn.style.backgroundImage = `url(/images/login/login-${i}.jpg) no-repeat center center`;
    i++;
}
</script>
```